# Apache reverse proxying for multiple URIs

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy

When using apache to reverse proxy, is it possible to forward http://somesite.com/ and http://somesite.com/foo to different servers? Say one goes to http://internalserver1/ and the other goes to http://internalserver2/foo

I can obviously just drop further down the path (ie http://somesite/bar) but its not desirable.

Comment: Take a look at [Nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/Main) as a reverse proxy over Apache, it's relatively new but has already surpassed LightHttp in use and it very fast and lightweight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it seems that order of directives in your vhost is important. and yes - you can achieve what you need. i just run test for:

```
ProxyPass /q http://host.one.com/img/
ProxyPass / http://another.host/
```

and it worked fine - all requests [ except those directed to /q/something ] ware proxied to another.host. those for /q/whatever - went to host.one.com

Comment: hmm, this didnt work for me, i ended up with the same issue without order - all links went to (in your example) another.host

did you include ProxyPassReverse?

Comment: @ANervousTwitch i'm sorry to hear it but this actually does work for me. no - i do not have ProxyPassReverse, only two lines for proxy: "ProxyPass /q http://stackoverflow.com/" and "ProxyPass /  http://serverfault.com/" after that.

Comment: @ANervousTwitch - i'm using apache 2.2.9-10 from debian.

Comment: I agree that this should work.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this using mod_rewrite.  It evaluates conditions in order and you can specify the [L] flag to make it stop processing further rules.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /foo/(.*) http://internalserver2/foo/$1 [P,L]
RewriteRule /(.*)     http://internalserver/$1 [P]
```

Full mod_rewrite documentation is at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html